# Can't access Android Server Socket

Tags: android, networking

Please excuse my bad English. It's not my main language.

Im trying to send Sensor data from my Android 8 Smartphone to my PC via a ServerSocket on the Smartphone. The problem is, that i cant connect to the ServerSocket. In PuTTY I get a Connection Timeout. I've tried to ping my device, but i get the Error: Remotehost unreachable. On Android 6 it works perfektly. I've disabled WiFi sleeping mode, but it still doesn't work. Also, I've included
 `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` in the AndroidManifest.xml file. I didn't include Code because I can't even ping the device. The Odd thing is, that I can ping my Computer from my device. Some more information: the Android 8 device is a Sony XPeria XA1 with current Android version.

Does anyone know why i can't access the ServerSocket? Logcat doesn't show any Errors. Ive found similar problems, but no solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved it myself. After pinging it from Linux, i can connect to the Server. I don't know what the reason was, but now can ping it from Windows too.